# vs code не печатает символ лямды

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code, utf-8

При попытки в vs code распечатать print('λ'), выдаёт ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\onmeshkov\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in 
print('\u03bb')
File "C:\Users\onmeshkov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03bb' in position 0: character maps to 
Кодировка в vs code стоит utf-8 хотя, пробовал разные, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно пофиксить?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать похожие вопросы по ошибке -- они задавались десятки раз

Comment: я искал, не нашёл ничего